# Saving node's fields without node itself in Drupal 8

Tags: nodes, 8

So in drupal 7 we can update node fields without saving the node itself via
field_attach_update.
Here the link :
https://www.urbaninsight.com/2011/10/24/saving-nodes-fields-without-saving-node-itself

Is there a DRUPAL 8 version of this? example please.